# Change the condition in while loop pyhton

Tags: python, while-loop

Instead of repeating the "if while block" due to different condition of variable "Default_factor" for every per 12 i would prefer to find a solution to change the condition ever 12th loop since I otherwise need to construct these blocks of "if while" until I have 500

```
if Months >= 1 :
    while per <= 12:

        Defaults = (
            1-(1-PdefaultValue['Default_factor'].iloc[0])**(1/12))*PrincipalAmount
        ActualPrincipal = (PrincipalAmount-(1-(1-PdefaultValue['Default_factor'].iloc[0])**(
            1/12))*PrincipalAmount)/(Months+Exp_ext-per+1)
        RecoovyWithLag = ((1-(1-PdefaultValue['Default_factor'].iloc[0])**(1/12))*PrincipalAmount) - (
            (1-(1-PdefaultValue['Default_factor'].iloc[0])**(1/12))*PrincipalAmount*Severity)
        ActualInterest = -npv.ipmt(Interest_Rate/12, 1, Months, PrincipalAmount-Defaults)
        CashInterest = ActualInterest - Cap_int
        PrincipalAmount = PrincipalAmount - ActualPrincipal - Defaults
        TotalCashFlow = RecoovyWithLag + ActualPrincipal + CashInterest
        CF.append(TotalCashFlow)  
       
    
        per += 1

if Months >= 13:
    while per > 12 and per <= 24:
        Defaults = (
            1-(1-PdefaultValue['Default_factor'].iloc[1])**(1/12))*PrincipalAmount
        ActualPrincipal = (PrincipalAmount-(1-(1-PdefaultValue['Default_factor'].iloc[1])**(
            1/12))*PrincipalAmount)/(Months+Exp_ext-per+1)
        RecoovyWithLag = ((1-(1-PdefaultValue['Default_factor'].iloc[1])**(1/12))*PrincipalAmount) - (
            (1-(1-PdefaultValue['Default_factor'].iloc[1])**(1/12))*PrincipalAmount*Severity)
        ActualInterest = - npv.ipmt(Interest_Rate/12, 1, Months, PrincipalAmount-Defaults)
        CashInterest = ActualInterest - Cap_int
        PrincipalAmount = PrincipalAmount - ActualPrincipal - Defaults
        TotalCashFlow = RecoovyWithLag + ActualPrincipal + CashInterest
        CF.append(TotalCashFlow)    
       
        per += 1
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code crammed together without any whitespace. Pretty hard to read, and it isn't runnable as-is. What's the actual difference between the two loop bodies? Can you simplify this into a [mre]?

Comment: it seems code in both `while` is the same - so you could put this code in function. And then code could be simpler and shorter

Comment: Yes it's obvious that I should have scaled down this code in order get it more practical, however so depending on value of "per" and "months"  the "Default_factor"-variable is fetching different values.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell what your code is doing, but I believe you're asking for a way to execute a certain bit of code on every 12th iteration of a loop. Here's a generic example of how you might do this:

```py
for month in range(100):
    if month % 12 == 0:
        print(month)
```

Which prints the following:

```py
0
12
24
36
48
60
72
84
96
```

This is because of the 'modulo' operator `%`, which calculates the remainder when dividing one number by another. With the line `if month % 12 == 0:` we're checking if the current value of month can be divided by 12 without any remainder, effectively returning `True` every 12 iterations (plus the 0th one, watch out for that).